# ASP .NET Gridview edit textbox adds spaces to the end of data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net

I have a Gridview that is being fed data from a local DB. The gridview has been set up so that you can edit that data that is in the row. However, when you try to edit data, there is trailing whitespace added to the text.

So when editing say a name like "Tom", the textbox will display "Tom........." (pretend the dots are spaces), and thats what the back end will receive as well.

I can't seem to figure out why. Code is below, any help appreciated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvActiveStudents" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="gvActiveStudents_RowDeleting" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvActiveStudents_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowEditing="gvActiveStudents_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvActiveStudents_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Inactive" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="Student ID" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
    protected void gvActiveStudents_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvActiveStudents.EditIndex = -1;
        getStudents();
    }
    protected void gvActiveStudents_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvActiveStudents.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        getStudents();
    }
```

Solution: Trim spaces in RowEditing

```
string firstname = ((TextBox)gvActiveStudents.Rows[index].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text.TrimEnd();
        ((TextBox)gvActiveStudents.Rows[index].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text = firstname;
string lastname = ((TextBox)gvActiveStudents.Rows[index].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text.TrimEnd();
        ((TextBox)gvActiveStudents.Rows[index].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text = lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [OnRowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) method call `Trim()` on the edited value before it is saved to the db.

Comment: Yes that's what I already do, but I want to remove the spaces before that, they shouldn't be there in the textbox in the first place.

Comment: Are they in the db? You could also strip on the RowEditing event.

Comment: The spaces aren't in the DB. I called trim when the data is loaded and the spaces still show up. How would I go about trimming in RowEditing?

Comment: Are there spaces in the text field or is the text field just extra wide like in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx. If you place the cursor in the field it's way right of the text?

Comment: Nvm, got it. Lengthy, but it works.

            string firstname = ((TextBox)gvActiveStudents.Rows[index].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text.TrimEnd();
            ((TextBox)gvActiveStudents.Rows[index].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text = firstname;

Comment: If I were to to click edit, and click the cursor to the far end of the textbox, enter in a letter, there will be spaces in between ("Tom.........t") and it will fail validation for being too long.

Answer (score -1):

If the datatype in the database is a fixed with string such as a nchar, then you should RTRIM() it anytime you return it, as SQL Server will pad out the string with whitespace.

FirstName stored as nchar(10) in database with a value of 'Tom'

`select FirstName from people returns 'Tom       '`

`select RTRIM(FirstName) from people returns 'Tom'`

Also if binding by name to anything remember to alias the column

`select RTRIM(FirstName) as FirstName from people`